# Modifying attributes of a shapefile using Java

Tags: shapefile, polygon, features, java

I have a polygon vector shapefile in which each feature has an integer attribute. I want to update this integer attribute (for all features) programmatically using Java on regular intervals of time.

How can I do this?

EDIT: I am using GeoServer to display my shapefile over the network. Since one of the attributes is continuously changing on a daily basis, I need to reflect that by modifying the shapefile. I want these changes to further reflect in GeoServer without restarting the GeoServer.

Comment: There are too many potential ways to answer question this without specifying what GIS software SDK you want to use.  Making changes to the dBase file itself on a realtime basis (which is easy) is going to have an impact on applications using the data (which is a whole different issue, and much more difficult to resolve).  Please **edit** the question to provide more details.

Comment: can you show us the code you have so far and what is not working for you

Comment: @Vince I added some more details.

Comment: @iant I have not written any code so far. I want to know what are the options i have.

Comment: @jps for that use case you should look at using a database like PostGIS as shapefiles won't work the way you want them to.